# What Temperature Will Electrons Escape Quantum Wells?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, semiconductor-physics, electronics

I'm watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nb6Wjq6STLc) video to understand quantum tunneling (Infinite Barrier/Particle in a Box model). The speaker says that electrons will most likely not gain the energy to escape a quantum well at room temperature (~300K). I was wondering when an electron *would* gain the energy necessary to escape a quantum well?

For reference, in the example, the electron in the quantum well has an energy of 0.2 eV and the speaker says it will need an energy of around 4 eV to escape the well (so basically, this question is about how an electron's energy varies with temperature).

Answer (score 1):

To get a rough idea, you can just convert the energy to a temperature with $E = k_b T$. For reference, 1 eV corresponds to around 11,000 K, at which point Si would be melted.

Also, my interpretation is that the speaker said 4 eV was needed for an electron to leave a chunk of semiconductor into vacuum. That number is just something he threw out there as an example. For reference, the actual number for Si would be ~1.4 eV.

0.2 eV is a much more reasonable depth for a quantum well.

Answer (score 1):

The temperature does not need to be very high to get some current. The Boltzmann factor may be small in a hot cathode but the number of electrons is enormous. In vacuum, there will be measurable current over about 1000 K due to thermionic emission.

This effect was used a lot in the era of vacuum-tube electronics. A filament would heat a cathode, for example barium oxide, and electrons would escape from the low-work-function material.